# Bitwise sum of two negative numbers

Tags: c, numbers, sum, bit-manipulation

I hope someone is able to help me.

I have the following algorithm that works both if I have two positive numbers or a positive and a negative number. It doesn't works, however, if both numbers are negative.

Can someone explain me how is it possible?

```
void sum (int p, int q) {

int sum, carry;

carry = 1;

while (carry > 0) {
    sum = p ^ q;
    carry = p & q;
    carry = carry << 1;
    p = sum;
    q = carry;
}

p = p << 1;
p = p >> 1;

printf("The result equals to %d", p);

}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone :)

Comment: Note that left-shifting negative integers is undefined behaviour. Your code only has defined semantics for non-overflowing sums of non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of two negative numbers is negative (unless an overflow occurs, as pointed out in a comment). But this code:

```
p = p << 1;
p = p >> 1;
```

is essentially clearing the topmost bit, i.e. the sign bit, so the result of this will never be negative.

Comment: Considering overflow, in C++ the sum of negative numbers is not always negative.</nitpicking>

Comment: I have tried to add a check: if both are negative numbers, that code shouldn't be executed, but it doesn't works. How is it possible?

Comment: if (p > 0 || q > 0) {
        p = p << 1;
        p = p >> 1;
    }